# Element reference null in Blazor

Tags: .net, blazor, ref

I have the following html razor code

```
<StEyth @ref="stEyth"></StEyth>
<Gr1D @ref="gr1D" ></Gr1D>
```

the following code in @code

```
@code {     
 private Gr1D?  gr1D;
 private StEyth? stEyth;
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()    
 {
   await updateView();
 }
 private async Task updateView()    
 {
   DrpdVal = new IpDrpdValues { ar1 = gr1D.ar1}
   await stEyth.updateView(DrpdVal);
 }
}
```

But gr1D is null when the code reaches

```
DrpdVal = new IpDrpdValues { ar1 = gr1D.ar1}
```

Any idea why?
And how could I get the values of the variables in the Gr1D?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `@ref` is set during the rendering. OnInitialized executes before the first render.

So the logical place to do this is in OnAfterRender. Use firstRender to do it only once.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
  if (firstRender)
  {
    await updateView();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct but please check my edited code. At 

await stEyth.updateView(DrpdVal);
updateview runs but does not affect the view of the component stEyth.



What I want to do is take some variables values from gr1D component and pass them to the component stEyth.
And after that the stEyth view should be updated

Comment: That is not the best way to communicate beween components. But calling `StateHasChanged()` inside `stEyth.updateView(DrpdVal)` might fix the direct problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks! And last question, what is the best way to communicate between components?

Comment: Either feed it with a parameter from the Parent or cascade a Service (and use notify events). It depends a lot on what kind of data, how it changes etc. The docs have a page or two on "Blazor State Management".

Comment: In my case, in Gr1D I want to select values from dropdownlists and then take these selected values and use them in other components

Answer (score 2):

If you add a yield in front of the call to `UpdateView` then the component runs it's initial render and the child components exist.

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        await UpdateView();
    }
```

However, if I read your comment above correctly, you're trying to co-ordinate data exchange between components.  This is pretty fraught with danger:  you aren't in control of the render and update process.  You should consider using a service to hold your data, and notification events your components can subscribe to.